# Windows triggering on custom URL scheme

Tags: windows, visual-c++, uri

I've created a custom URL scheme on my Windows 10 machine. 
I trigger the URL scheme to start my application which is connected the the scheme.

myapp:name="Test"

myapp is the custom scheme connected to MytestURIApp.exe.
It seems to work in launching MytestURIApp.exe.

I have 2 questions here.  If MytestURIApp.exe is not running already the entry point when triggering the URL scheme should be the main(...)  function where I can catch the URI sent ?

If the application is already running how do I register an entry point from here?
If already running I want to be able to check that the URI sent is a valid one and then do some stuff.

Thanks

Comment: **(1)** You specify that when you register the application. Normally, you'd have the URL passed to you on the command line. For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx **(2)** If you use `DDEEXEC` registration mechanism (unlikely, based on your question), then the OS will communicate the URL to the already-running instance of your application using DDE protocol. Otherwise, it'll just run another instance.

Comment: My question is do I have to implement something to handle when my application is already running ?

Comment: Not if you are happy with multiple instances of your application running at the same time.